# How to set or skip a package configuration on PECL?

Tags: php, redis, continuous-integration, travis-ci, pecl

I'm running `pecl install redis` on Travis, but its hanging on:

```
enable igbinary serializer support? [no] :
```

How can I set or skip this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m6w6's answer will respond "yes" (or "no") to every configuration option.

If this isn't what you want, you should use the `--configureoptions` flag of `pecl install`.

You'll want to find the package.xml for your package to see the configurable options and their defaults. For `redis`, you'd go here:

https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/develop/package.xml

Search for the `<configureoption>` tags, which in this case are:

```xml
<configureoption name="enable-redis-igbinary" prompt="enable igbinary serializer support?" default="no"/>
<configureoption name="enable-redis-lzf" prompt="enable lzf compression support?" default="no"/>
<configureoption name="enable-redis-zstd" prompt="enable zstd compression support?" default="no"/>
```

You can then pass these options along to the install command like so:

```bash
pecl install --configureoptions 'enable-redis-igbinary="yes" enable-redis-lzf="no" enable-redis-zstd="no"' redis
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that would be the correct usage instead of a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Try `yes | pecl install redis` or `yes no | pecl install redis`.

`yes` is a program of the GNU coreutils package:

```
$ yes --help
Usage: yes [STRING]...
  or:  yes OPTION
Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or 'y'.
```